# Using SHA to encrypt password input on a form

Tags: sha

I know you like to see code, so here it is. All I want to do is to encrypt the password using SHA as it is entered. I have managed to encrypt the mysql database field to match it already.

I can't seem to find the correct syntax so I get a row of blobs instead of the password in clear text, which means it is not being sent to the server encrypted.

Thanks

```
<body>
<div id="container">

<div id="logo"><img src="images/Logo.jpg" alt="mycena"  />

<div id="banner">
    <h1>Shropshire Fungus Group</h1>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="ruler">
<hr />
</div>
</div>
<div class="menu"><ul class="nav" >
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Membership</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Newsletters</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Fixture List</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Useful Links</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="intro">
<h2>Please complete your details to log in</h2>
<table>
<tr>
  <td> Username: </td>
  <td><input type="text" name="user" id="user" size="35" maxlength="50"/></td>
</tr>
<!-- password should be 8 characters or more in length -->
<tr>
  <td> Password: </td>
  <td><input type="text" name="upword" id="upword" size="40" maxlength="40"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<form  action="loginphp170114.php" method="post" id="demo">
<input type="submit" value="Submit form" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use an external library such as [this one](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/), or else implement the sha1 algorithm yourself.

Note that sha1 is hashing, not encryption, and it's not a hash algorithm designed for storing passwords, so it's easily broken.

Comment: SHA-1 is not the best hashing to use nowadays but it's not really "easily broken", as long as the password is complex and long enough.

Comment: Everything I've read says to use hashes designed for this purpose such as bcrypt. A quick google search found a site that claims you can crack sha1 passwords in about a day.  http://www.warmenhoven.co/2012/03/06/do-not-use-md5-or-sha1-to-simply-hash-db-passwords/

Comment: SHA-1 is easily broken due to Rainbow tables, bcrypt is great just make sure you generate a random salt for each password.

Comment: @Tim: Not really. They assume 8 alphanumeric characters only. Like I said, having a complex password, with special characters, numbers and around 10 characters long, or more, makes cracking essentially impossible, even with very powerful computers. Yes, bcrypt is better, especially if you bump up the number of rounds of it, but increasing password length makes the brute forcing exponentially harder. SHA1 is still quite alright with a good password policy. But yes, if one can go with bcrypt, it is better.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll spend some time tomorrow trying to figure out what they mean!